# Why does my image is not rendered using Next.JS Image tag and only the alt text is shown?

Tags: tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I'm using next/image and my image just won't show in the browser, only the alt text.

My goal is to display an image with rounded corners and centered. Am I missing something?

The code is the following:

```
import Image from "next/image";      

<div className="relative h-32 w-32 mx-auto overflow-hidden">
        <Image
          src="/images/pp.jpg"
          alt="profile pic"
          width={500}
          height={500}
          className="rounded-full object-cover object-center"
        />
</div>
```

I'm using Next.JS 14 for this, and the image is already located inside the `public` directory.

I already tried to replace with the regular HTML img tag, I've tried different weight and height, I tried different h- and w-, I tried changing from overflow-hidden to overflow-auto, no success.

If you want to see how that output is: https://prnt.sc/xaO-n8De6RtK

Comment: Images folders is inside the public directory? And you have imported Image component correctly like `import Image from 'next/image'`? I'd see [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#required-props).

Comment: It didn't help... objectFit and others throw me a decaprication warning, that's why I'm using className there, also it still didn't render the image. Just added a print of my code output now, maybe it's clearer

Comment: What about directly putting the image in the public directory? i.e not inside images folder.

Comment: Is it public\images ?  And not possible you have images ABOVE public ? So it can't find it.  If that is the case try adding a .. to denote going back a directory like this:
"../images/pp.jpg"     This might not be the case, but if it was, this is usually a way to make it work.

Comment: Not even putting on public folder directly not changing the path. I guess since I can use HTML's img tag with the same path, it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I am getting a:

"Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <a>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error"

is it related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug this issue by doing the following to the src attribute:

```
src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4OiAcEKYFke_7WcK6Effo5EZ-eXFLN9u6Fm6qdOMn&s"
```

You'd get the desired result because the image can be found.

The actual solution to your bug will be to correctly input the correct path of the image to the src attribute and that you have the correct filename and extension.